# rack ssl and nginx configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, dragonfly-gem

Hi I am trying to use rack ssl with my nginx. Everything works fine on all pages apart from my statics dragonfly images which is serve as a proxy via nginx. Here is that part of the config (ofc when in non ssl mode all images serves just fine). Any idea how to solve this?:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:443;
    server_name server.com;
    root /home/rails/production/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;


    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate some.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key some.key;

    location /home {
       rewrite ^ https://www.example.com/ permanent;
    }


    location /media {
       try_files $uri @media;
    }

    location @media {
       proxy_redirect         off;

       proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/nginx-production.sock;
       proxy_store /home/rails/production/current/public$uri;
       proxy_store_access user:rw group:rw all:r;
     }


}
```

EDIT ------

Ok I got abit further. I found a section of my nginx conf that had this:

```
server {
   listen unix:/tmp/nginx-production.sock;
   root /home/rails/production/current/public;
   passenger_enabled on;
   rails_env staging;
 }
```

ofc you see rails_env was wrong so i changed it to production and all images returns fine if it was not populated via a ajax request.. so the hunt goes on :(

EDIT ------
found this also. All image that does not render under ssl have a URL of: https:///media/ chrome shows a 502

but ones that does redner have:
https:///media/?

Am starting to this is somthing with the way dragonfly is used? Then why is it ok for some and not other...